# How to load initial state in a flux store asynchronously?

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Till now whatever, react+flux apps that I have built, constructing the initial state of the store was easy as per the requirements of the app. I could just use simple JS objects, or in case the state needed to be persisted, I used localStorage which has a synchronous api, thus resulting in the state being available when getInitialState was called.

```
getInitialState() {
   return State.getInitialState();//synchronous method which returns state
}
```

However, as per the current requirements, I have to save and retrieve the state from indexeddb, whose api is asynchronous. Thus, the intialState I get currently is undefined which leads to invariant violation error.

Is it at all possible to load the initialState in the store asynchronously?

Comment: Two options: give the app a local initial state to use until the async call completes, or, give the components enough logic to handle an incomplete state. For example, in an app I recently built, I load graph data asynchronously. Each Graph component displays a loading message until its props data array has data, since each component knows that its props data array will never be empty.

Comment: Look at the examples for server side rendering with [mern](http://mern.io/). There's no correct way to do it, but I thought those examples seemed particularly sensible.

Answer (score 0):

lets say your store has a getInitialState() method. and that returns some object with all of the data in the store. you should specify defaults within the store that your component should have.

```
class ExampleStore {
    constructor(){
        this.something = false
        this.somethingElse = false
        this.someData = {}
    }
    getInitialState(){
        return {
            something: this.something,
            somethingElse: this.somethingElse,
            someData: this.someData,
        };
    }
}
```

the reason why you want to go with this method is because you don't want to duplicate code in every component just to wait for the async call. Let the store return some defaults and then when new data comes in and assigns it to the store update the component with a store change function.